# Get First/Second occurrence of a column based on values in another column - Oracle

Tags: oracle, dense-rank

I wanted to get `DESC_TXT` for two scenarios:

When `STEP_NAM` = `GCP` - i wanted the Second occurrence of  `DESC_TXT` which is `TR/VR/NF`  (3rd Row)

When `STEP_NAM` = `CA` - i wanted the FIRST occurrence of  `DESC_TXT` which is `QS/SC/S`   (4th Row)

`TR_NUM     RN_REF_CD       DESC_TXT    TRN_DTTM        STEP_NAM
22938243    20180106-0220   null        1/6/2018 19:35  CF
22954518    20180106-0220   IT/SI/WS    1/8/2018 18:32  GCP
22957994    20180106-0220   TR/VR/NF    1/9/2018 10:05  GCP
22958126    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 10:08  CA
22958125    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 10:08  CA
22958135    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 10:08  GCP
22958136    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 10:08  GCP
22958140    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 10:08  SBP
22959829    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:14  SBP
22959827    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:14  SBP
22959828    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:14  SBP
22959830    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:14  SBP
22959873    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:15  OIP
22959936    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:17  SBP
22959945    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:17  OIP
22959956    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:18  SBP
22959955    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:18  SBP
22959953    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:18  SBP
22959954    20180106-0220   QS/SC/S     1/9/2018 11:18  SBP
22960468    20180106-0220   null        1/9/2018 11:39  ERA
22964031    20180106-0220   null        1/9/2018 14:59  SBP
22964032    20180106-0220   null        1/9/2018 14:59  SBP
22964033    20180106-0220   null        1/9/2018 14:59  SBP
22964029    20180106-0220   null        1/9/2018 14:59  OSI
22964030    20180106-0220   null        1/9/2018 14:59  SBP`

The Dataset is ordered by ~TRN_DTTM`

The Final output would be - something like this:

`RN_REF_CD       DESC_TXT1   DESC_TXT2

20180106-0220    TR/VR/NF     QS/SC/S`

and wanted this to repeat for each `RN_REF_CD`.

Answer (score 1):

```
with s (tr_num, rn_ref_cd, desc_txt, trn_dttm, step_nam) as (
select 22938243, '20180106-0220', null      ,   to_date('1/6/2018 19:35', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'CF'  from dual union all
select 22954518, '20180106-0220', 'IT/SI/WS',   to_date('1/8/2018 18:32', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'GCP' from dual union all
select 22957994, '20180106-0220', 'TR/VR/NF',   to_date('1/9/2018 10:05', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'GCP' from dual union all
select 22958126, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 10:08', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'CA'  from dual union all
select 22958125, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 10:08', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'CA'  from dual union all
select 22958135, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 10:08', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'GCP' from dual union all
select 22958136, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 10:08', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'GCP' from dual union all
select 22958140, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 10:08', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22959829, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:14', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22959827, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:14', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22959828, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:14', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22959830, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:14', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22959873, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:15', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'OIP' from dual union all
select 22959936, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:17', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22959945, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:17', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'OIP' from dual union all
select 22959956, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:18', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22959955, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:18', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22959953, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:18', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22959954, '20180106-0220', 'QS/SC/S' ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:18', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22960468, '20180106-0220', null      ,   to_date('1/9/2018 11:39', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'ERA' from dual union all
select 22964031, '20180106-0220', null      ,   to_date('1/9/2018 14:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22964032, '20180106-0220', null      ,   to_date('1/9/2018 14:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22964033, '20180106-0220', null      ,   to_date('1/9/2018 14:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual union all
select 22964029, '20180106-0220', null      ,   to_date('1/9/2018 14:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'OSI' from dual union all
select 22964030, '20180106-0220', null      ,   to_date('1/9/2018 14:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'SBP' from dual)
select rn_ref_cd, 
max(case when rn = 2 and step_nam = 'GCP' then desc_txt end) desc_txt1,
max(case when rn = 1 and step_nam = 'CA'  then desc_txt end) desc_txt2
from
  (select rn_ref_cd, desc_txt, step_nam,
   row_number() over (partition by rn_ref_cd, step_nam order by trn_dttm)  rn
   from s
  )
group by rn_ref_cd;

RN_REF_CD     DESC_TXT DESC_TXT
------------- -------- --------
20180106-0220 TR/VR/NF QS/SC/S
```

Answer (score 0):

** Was able to fetch data with this query, hope this helps:-**

```
    SELECT RNREFCD,DESCTXT1,DESCTXT4 FROM (Select  RNREFCD,DESCTXT1,DESCTXT2 From
    (
    Select Row_Number() OVER (Order by TRNDTTM) rno, e.RNREFCD as RNREFCD,E.DESCTXT  DESCTXT1 ,'' DESCTXT2
        From Emp e
        WHERE (e.STEPNAM  in ('GCP' ) 
    )
    )
    Where mod(rno,2) =0) a,(Select  RNREFCD1,DESCTXT3,DESCTXT4 From
    (
    Select Row_Number() OVER (Order by TRNDTTM) rno, e.RNREFCD as RNREFCD1,''  DESCTXT3 ,E.DESCTXT  DESCTXT4
        From Emp e
        WHERE (e.STEPNAM  in ('CA' ) 
    )
    )
    Where mod(rno,2) =1)b;
```